# How to persist classes like java.util.Currency?

Tags: java, hibernate, persistence

I am using hibernate to persist my data. It's a financial application and I am having a hard time persisting the most fundamental entity of the application which is 'Money'. I was using JodaMoney but it's immutable so I am not able to find a good way to persist it. And without persisting my money to database, there is no point of making the application. What would I do with the immutability when I can't even store the state of my object?
Then I started creating my own 'Money'(fields as BigDecimal amount and java.util.Currency for currency), I wanted to use 'Currency' of java.util . But, that doesn't have a public constructor so hibernate can not persist that.
Please guide me on how to deal with this?

EDIT1: The code for most basic class:

```
@Entity
public class BasicMoney {

    @Embedded
    @Id
    private BigDecimal amount;
    @Embedded
    private Currency currency;
    //getters and setters, other methods
}
```

Now, when I make an object of this class and try to store it into database, it doesn't work. Hibernate throws:

> org.hibernate.InstantiationException: No default constructor for entity:  : java.util.Currency

So, this is the problem which I am facing.

Comment: lots of theory, no code....this is not a good way of asking a question!!!

Comment: Post what you have tried

Comment: @AnkitLamba I have added the code, its a very basic code though, but my main question is how to deal with such situations?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You could use a workaround

```
@Embedded
String currency; //store data as a string

public void setCurrency(Currency currency) {
    this.currency = currency.getCurrencyCode(); //conversion to an actual currency
}

public Currency getCurrency() {
    return Currency.getInstance(currency); //conversion to an actual currency
}
```

Comment: Thanks a lot!!! that makes much sense. I have only one concern with this, every time I call getCurrency() method, it will have to create new currency object, so wouldn't that be expensive? A work around which I can think for this is making another '@Transient' field which permanently stores the Currency object so getter doesn't have to construct it everytime it gets called. what do you think about this?

Comment: try System.out.println(Currency.getInstance("USD") == Currency.getInstance("USD")); it returns true

Comment: okay yes its returning true, so that means Currency class is returning the same instance. I just checked the method in java.util.Currency also, and I get it, it is maintaining a Map of currency objects with String Key. So, it doesn't construct new objects everytime. Thanks again Evgeniy ! :)

Comment: I get a compiler error @Embedded attribute type should not be a 'String'

Answer (score 6):

Instead of dealing with a currency string and an amount, teach Hibernate about your type instead. That way you would have:

```
private Money amount;
```

instead of

```
private BigDecimal amount;
private String currency;
```

so you don't need to convert all over the place.

Here's how I do it:

1) Instead of JodaMoney, use [JavaMoney](https://github.com/JavaMoney/jsr354-ri), the JSR-354 project that is expected to be included in Java 9. If you want to stick to JodaMoney, you don't need step #3 below.

2) Add this [UserType library](http://jadira.sourceforge.net/usertype-userguide.html) to your classpath

3) Create this simple class:

```
   public class CustomPersistentMoneyAmountAndCurrency extends AbstractMultiColumnUserType<MonetaryAmount> {  

    private static final ColumnMapper<?, ?>[] COLUMN_MAPPERS = new ColumnMapper<?, ?>[] { new CustomStringColumnCurrencyUnitMapper(), new BigDecimalBigDecimalColumnMapper() };

    private static final String[] PROPERTY_NAMES = new String[]{ "currency", "number" };

    @Override
    protected ColumnMapper<?, ?>[] getColumnMappers() {
        return COLUMN_MAPPERS;
    }

    @Override
    protected Money fromConvertedColumns(Object[] convertedColumns) {

        CurrencyUnit currencyUnitPart = (CurrencyUnit) convertedColumns[0];
        BigDecimal amountPart = (BigDecimal) convertedColumns[1];
        return Money.of(amountPart, currencyUnitPart);
    }

    @Override
    protected Object[] toConvertedColumns(MonetaryAmount value) {

        return new Object[] { value.getCurrency(), value.getNumber().numberValue(BigDecimal.class) };
    }

    @Override
    public String[] getPropertyNames() {
        return PROPERTY_NAMES;
    }
}
```

4) Now wherever you want to use this in your Entities you would do:

```
   @TypeDefs(value = {
        @TypeDef(name = "moneyAmountWithCurrencyType", typeClass =        CustomPersistentMoneyAmountAndCurrency.class)
})
@Entity
@Table(name = "account_entry")
public class AccountEntry {

    private Money referenceMoney;
    ...
    @Basic( optional = false )
    @Columns(columns = {
            @Column( name = "reference_money_currency", nullable = false, length = 3  ),
            @Column( name = "reference_money", nullable = false  )
    })
    @Type(type = "moneyAmountWithCurrencyType")
    public Money getReferenceMoney() {
        return this.referenceMoney;
    }
  }
```

And that's it. You will get strong typing all throughout.

Answer (score 6):

Hibernate does support java.util.Currency natively.
https://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/3.6/reference/en-US/html/types.html#types-basic-value-currency

Answer (score 4):

Sorry for the late answer, but I didn´t see this option as an answer and I think is pretty elegant. You can use a JPA converter with autoapply:

```
@Converter(autoApply = true)
public class CurrencyConverter implements AttributeConverter<Currency, String> {

    @Override
    public String convertToDatabaseColumn(Currency currency) {
        return currency.getCurrencyCode();
    }

    @Override
    public Currency convertToEntityAttribute(String currencyCode) {
        return Currency.getInstance(currencyCode);
    }
}
```